# Linux bonding failover issue between two cisco switch

Tags: linux, bonding, nsswitch, failover

[image]

I have above scenario where server has `bond0` interface connected to SW1 and SW2 relevant interface of server, last night somehow `SW1` got rebooted and server lost `eth0` connectivity but it didn't failover to eth1 also every after switch rebooted successfully network was down and this happened on multiple server not single. so finally i have restart network on all server to make it work. we have `primary=eth0` set in bond0 configuration.

ifcfg-bond0

```
DEVICE=bond0
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
BONDING_OPTS=mode=1 arp_interval=1000 arp_ip_target=192.168.10.1 miimon=500 downdelay=1000 primary=eth0 primary_reselect=always
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
IPADDR=192.168.10.20
GATEWAY=192.168.10.1
```

ifcfg-eth0

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes
```

ifcfg-eth1

```
DEVICE=eth1
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes
```

This is what i am seeing in logs when this happened

```
[root@server1 ~]# cat /var/log/messages | grep eth
Jun 8 05:03:05 s_sys@server1.example.com kernel: : bnx2 0000:02:00.0: eth0: NIC Copper Link is Down
Jun 8 05:03:05 s_sys@server1.example.com kernel: : bonding: bond0: link status definitely down for interface eth0, disabling it
Jun 8 05:03:05 s_sys@server1.example.com kernel: : bonding: bond0: making interface eth1 the new active one.
Jun 8 05:07:03 s_sys@server1.example.com kernel: : bnx2 0000:02:00.0: eth0: NIC Copper Link is Up, 1000 Mbps full duplex
Jun 8 05:07:03 s_sys@server1.example.com kernel: : bonding: bond0: link status definitely up for interface eth0.
Jun 8 05:20:45 s_sys@server1.example.com kernel: : bonding: bond0: Removing slave eth0
Jun 8 05:20:45 s_sys@server1.example.com kernel: : bonding: bond0: Warning: the permanent HWaddr of eth0 - 18:A9:05:3A:39:1D - is still in use by bond0. Set the HWaddr of eth0 to a different address to avoid conflicts.
Jun 8 05:20:45 s_sys@server1.example.com kernel: : bonding: bond0: releasing backup interface eth0
Jun 8 05:20:46 s_sys@server1.example.com kernel: : bonding: bond0: Removing slave eth1
Jun 8 05:20:46 s_sys@server1.example.com kernel: : bonding: bond0: releasing active interface eth1
Jun 8 05:20:46 s_sys@server1.example.com kernel: : bonding: bond0: Adding slave eth0.
Jun 8 05:20:46 s_sys@server1.example.com kernel: : bnx2 0000:02:00.0: eth0: using MSIX
Jun 8 05:20:46 s_sys@server1.example.com kernel: : bonding: bond0: enslaving eth0 as a backup interface with a down link.
Jun 8 05:20:46 s_sys@server1.example.com kernel: : bonding: bond0: Adding slave eth1.
Jun 8 05:20:46 s_sys@server1.example.com kernel: : bnx2 0000:02:00.1: eth1: using MSIX
Jun 8 05:20:46 s_sys@server1.example.com kernel: : bonding: bond0: enslaving eth1 as a backup interface with a down link.
Jun 8 05:20:49 s_sys@server1.example.com kernel: : bnx2 0000:02:00.0: eth0: NIC Copper Link is Up, 1000 Mbps full duplex
Jun 8 05:20:49 s_sys@server1.example.com kernel: : bonding: bond0: link status definitely up for interface eth0.
Jun 8 05:20:49 s_sys@server1.example.com kernel: : bonding: bond0: making interface eth0 the new active one.
Jun 8 05:20:49 s_sys@server1.example.com kernel: : bnx2 0000:02:00.1: eth1: NIC Copper Link is Up, 1000 Mbps full duplex
Jun 8 05:20:50 s_sys@server1.example.com kernel: : bonding: bond0: link status definitely up for interface eth1.
```

Comment: anyone has any suggestion?